# Importing an Enum into a Visual Basic class so that it becomes inheritable

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Here is what I have in my file

```
Option Strict On
Imports MyNameSpace.MyEnum

Public Class AwesomeClass

    Public Function Foo (ByVal Bar As MyEnum) As Object
        'Do Something
        Return Nothing
    End Function

End Class
```

What I want to do is this:

```
Option Strict On

Public Class SubAwesomeClass
    Inherits AwesomeClass

    Public Function Zazz (ByVal Bar As MyEnum) As Object
        'Do Something
        Return Nothing
    End Function    

End Class
```

But since MyEnum isn't defined in the subclass it won't work.  I am not very familiar with what these types of things are called, but I think that I am import a type definition of sorts.  Since I am Importing, and not defining, it is only available in the first file. Basically, I want to include MyEnum as part of the class but I don't how to do it.  I don't want to copy/paste it over, and I don't really want to write Imports ... at the top of all of my subclasses.

Are there any other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Enum is unrelated to the inheritance tree.  Just use "Imports MyNameSpace.MyEnum" in the child class as well.

Comment: That is probably the right solution, but is there any other way?  There is also a lot of other code I have that depends on the existence `MyEnum` being a member of `AwesomeClass` and that all breaks when I use imports as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can also change the type definition of the parameters to be fully qualified:

```
Public Function Foo (ByVal Bar As MyNameSpace.MyEnum) As Object

Public Function Zazz (ByVal Bar As MyNameSpace.MyEnum) As Object
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put the Public declaration of the enum inside Awesome class.